# Why has the Greek goverment removed unvaccinated doctors from their positions until vaccinated?

Tags: covid-19, public-health, greece, vaccine

According to a [recent law](https://www.news24.com/news24/world/news/10-000-unvaccinated-greek-health-workers-face-suspension-union-20210901), the Greek Government now mandates vaccination against Covid-19 for doctors and workers in elderly-care homes and medical staff. If they are not vaccinated they are removed from work until they get vaccinated.

This caused outrage among health workers. But why did the Greek government do this? I mean they could use the same law as is currently in force for all workers, who are obliged to do regular tests until vaccinated.

Many workers are unable to work because of this and Hellenic (Greek) hospitals are understaffed.

Answer (score 4):

It's hard for me to say what the Greek government is thinking would happen, but [e.g. in the US](https://medicalxpress.com/news/2021-09-unvaccinated-workers-theyd-shot.html), despite many workers telling pollsters they would quit if their employers instituted a vaccine mandate... much fewer actually did that, particularly in healthcare.

> We found that 16% of employed respondents would quit, start looking for other employment or both if their employer instituted a mandate. Among those who said they were "vaccine hesitant"—almost a quarter of respondents—we found that 48% would quit or look for another job.
>
> Other polls have shown similar results. A Kaiser Family Foundation survey put the share of workers who would quit at 50%. [...]
>
> But while it is easy and cost-free to tell a pollster you'll quit your job, actually doing so when it means losing a paycheck you and your family may depend upon is another matter.
>
> Houston Methodist Hospital, for example, required its 25,000 workers to get a vaccine by June 7. Before the mandate, about 15% of its employees were unvaccinated. By mid-June, that percentage had dropped to 3% and hit 2% by late July. A total of 153 workers were fired or resigned, while another 285 were granted medical or religious exemptions and 332 were allowed to defer it.
>
> At Jewish Home Family in Rockleigh, New Jersey, only five of its 527 workers quit following its vaccine mandate. Two out of 250 workers left Westminster Village in Bloomington, Illinois, and even in deeply conservative rural Alabama, a state with one of the lowest vaccine uptake rates, Hanceville Nursing & Rehab Center lost only six of its 260 employees. [...]
>
> And at Indiana University Health, the 125 workers who quit are out of 35,800 total employees, or 0.3%.